# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous (numerical)

Tags: python, random, numpy, scipy

I'm stuck with an error and I can't manage to find a solution for it. This is my function:

```
def rep(N,list,t):
     result=0
     for i in range(N):
         if((list[i]-t)<=t):
             result = result + 1
         else:
             result = result + 0
     return(result/N)
```

Then I try to plot the function :

```
 plt.plot(x,rep(1000,nEchant,x))
```

And this is what I get :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#114>", line 1, in <module>
     plt.plot(x,rep(1000,nEchant,x))
   File "<pyshell#113>", line 4, in rep
     if((list[i]-1)<=t):
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your definition, avoid calling the second argument `list`, as this shadows the built in function.  Can you show what `nEchant` looks like?

Comment: x is a list\array, i assume since you try to plot against it. which becomes t in the function. maybe you wanted t[i] in there?

Comment: `rep`only returns a single value, if it was to work. Is that intended?    Seems a bit silly to plot a single value.

Comment: if t was a list, there would be an error with `-` between 2 lists.

Comment: @njzk2 correct, but they might be numpy arrays. OP, answer the questions please, and show some more of the code. Trying to solve the puzzle, with half the pieces missing, is not very productive.

Comment: Either list[i] or t is an array. If statements need Booleans; arrays don't have an implicit cast to Boolean. You could use np.any or np.all interchangeably if it is a singleton array; but considering t is passed to the x arg of plot aswell, it probably is infact an array, and youll have to think yourself what kind of reduction to a boolean makes sense for your appliction

Comment: nEchant is a list, I've built it by appending random values to it.

Comment: t is supposed to be a real number. I've built x like this : 

     x=np.arange(-5,5,0.001)

Comment: Ok got it guys, thanks a lot!! Indeed, x, the way I built it is an array!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the expression `(list[i]-t)<=t` is returning a numpy array. To ensure that *all* values of `list[i]-t` are less than `t`, use:

```
numpy.all((list[i]-t)<=t)
```